Mocks in Ceedling Project – Files Were Not Found
I am trying to write unit tests for files present inside the pmk folder of this project: https://github.com/air-gmv/air/tree/master/air, but I'm having trouble getting mocks to work correctly. My mocks aren't being generated, and I keep getting errors stating that files weren't found.
I expected Ceedling to generate a mock file mock_pmk.h, but this is not happening.
In my test file test_pmk_core_error.c, I include the mock like this:
#include "mock_pmk.h"

However, when I run the tests, I receive an error saying the file cannot be found. Am I missing something in my configuration or project structure? What could be causing the file not found error?
Configuration (project.yml):
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - +:/home/gmv/air-dev/air/pmk/core/**
    - -:/home/gmv/air-dev/air/pmk/core/include/**
  :support:
    - test/support
  :libraries: []
  :include:
    - stubs
    - /home/gmv/air-dev/air/pmk/core/include

:files:
   :include: 
     - +:/home/gmv/air-dev/air/pmk/core/include/**


Is that the complete project.yml file? Otherwise, provide the whole contend of the file. What version of Ceedling are you using?

Here are the key details of my setup:
Ceedling Version: Using gem version of Ceedling
Unity Version: 2.6.0
CMock Version: 2.5.4
CException Version: 1.3.4

The file is too long. This is the general configuration:
:project:
:which_ceedling: gem
:ceedling_version: '?'
:use_exceptions: FALSE
:use_test_preprocessor: :all
:use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
:use_mocks: TRUE
:build_root: build
:test_file_prefix: test_
:default_tasks:
- test:all
:test_threads: 1
:compile_threads: 1

This is the CMock Configuration
:cmock:
:mock_prefix: mock_
:when_no_prototypes: :warn
:use_test_preprocessor: :all
:enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
:plugins:
- :ignore
- :callback
:treat_as:
uint8:    HEX8
uint16:   HEX16
uint32:   UINT32
int8:     INT8
bool:     UINT8

Try to add /** after :paths:   :include:      - /home/gmv/air-dev/air/pmk/core/include   and remove :files:   :include:      - +:/home/gmv/air-dev/air/pmk/core/include/**. Is stubs meant to be a path?
